# Implementation of a time lock with Python's asyncio

Tags: python, locking, python-asyncio

I have no idea if this kind of lock is called time lock, but I need something for the following scenario: I'm making a lot of concurrent requests with `aiohttp`, and it's possible that the server at some point returns `429 Too Many Requests`. In that instance, I have to pause all my subsequent requests for some time.

I came up with the following solution:

```py
import asyncio


class TimeLock:

    def __init__(self, *, loop=None):
        self._locked = False
        self._locked_at = None
        self._time_lock = None
        self._unlock_task = None
        self._num_waiters = 0
        if loop is not None:
            self._loop = loop
        else:
            self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def __repr__(self):
        state = f'locked at {self.locked_at}' if self._locked else 'unlocked'
        return f'[{state}] {self._num_waiters} waiters'

    @property
    def locked(self):
        return self._locked

    @property
    def locked_at(self):
        return self._locked_at

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.acquire()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        # in this time lock there is nothing to do when it's released
        return

    async def acquire(self):
        if not self._locked:
            return True
        try:
            print('waiting for lock to be released')
            self._num_waiters += 1
            await self._time_lock
            self._num_waiters -= 1
            print('done, returning now')
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            if self._locked:
                raise
        return True

    def lock_for(self, delay, lock_more=False):
        print(f'locking for {delay}')
        if self._locked:
            if not lock_more:
                # if we don't want to increase the lock time, we just exit when
                # the lock is already in a locked state
                print('already locked, nothing to do')
                return
            print('already locked, but canceling old unlock task')
            self._unlock_task.cancel()
        self._locked = True
        self._locked_at = time.time()
        self._time_lock = self._loop.create_future()
        self._unlock_task = self._loop.create_task(self.unlock_in(delay))
        print('locked')

    async def unlock_in(self, delay):
        print('unlocking started')
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        self._locked = False
        self._locked_at = None
        self._unlock_task = None
        self._time_lock.set_result(True)
        print('unlocked')
```

I am testing the lock with this code:

```py
import asyncio

from ares.http import TimeLock


async def run(lock, i):
    async with lock:
        print(lock)
        print(i)
        if i in (3, 6, 9):
            lock.lock_for(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = TimeLock()
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(run(lock, i))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    print(lock)
```

The code produces the following output, which seems to be consistent with what I want from the above scenario:

```
[unlocked] 0 waiters
0
[unlocked] 0 waiters
1
[unlocked] 0 waiters
2
[unlocked] 0 waiters
3
locking for 2
locked
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
waiting for lock to be released
unlocking started
unlocked
done, returning now
[unlocked] 5 waiters
4
done, returning now
[unlocked] 4 waiters
5
done, returning now
[unlocked] 3 waiters
6
locking for 2
locked
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 2 waiters
7
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 1 waiters
8
done, returning now
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 0 waiters
9
locking for 2
already locked, nothing to do
unlocking started
[locked at 1559496296.7109463] 0 waiters
```

Is this the proper way to implement this synchronization primitive?
I am also not sure about the thread-safety of this code. I don't have too much experience with threads and asyncio code.

Comment: I am not sure if this a good or common practice in terms of locking. But there are no "threads" in asyncio. "Everything" runs in one "thread", this is why everything locks if you block the eventloop with some slow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test your code, but idea seems to be fine. You should worry about thread-safety only if you're going to use same lock object in different threads. As Jimmy Engelbrecht already noted asyncio runs in single thread and you usually don't have to worry about thread-safety of primitives.

Here's few more thoughts:

- I'm note sure about terminology, but it seems this primitive should be called [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))
- Instead of implementing it from the begging you can inherit or just use [existing primitive(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html)
- You can delegate to semaphore tracking of events when if should pause instead of doing it inside client code

This code snippet shows the idea:

```
import asyncio


class PausingSemaphore:
    def __init__(self, should_pause, pause_for_seconds):
        self.should_pause = should_pause
        self.pause_for_seconds = pause_for_seconds
        self._is_paused = False
        self._resume = asyncio.Event()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.check_paused()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        if self.should_pause(exc):
            self.pause()

    async def check_paused(self):
        if self._is_paused:
            await self._resume.wait()

    def pause(self):
        if not self._is_paused:
            self._is_paused = True
            asyncio.get_running_loop().call_later(
                self.pause_for_seconds,
                self.unpause
            )

    def unpause(self):
        self._is_paused = False
        self._resume.set()
```

Let's test it:

```
import aiohttp


def should_pause(exc):
    return (
        type(exc) is aiohttp.ClientResponseError 
        and
        exc.status == 429
    )


pausing_sem = None
regular_sem = None


async def request(url):
    async with regular_sem:
        async with pausing_sem:
            try:
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    async with session.get(url, raise_for_status=True) as resp:
                        print('Done!')
            except aiohttp.ClientResponseError:
                print('Too many requests!')
                raise


async def main():
    global pausing_sem
    global regular_sem
    pausing_sem = PausingSemaphore(should_pause, 5)
    regular_sem = asyncio.Semaphore(3)

    await asyncio.gather(
        *[
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/status/429'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
            request('http://httpbin.org/get'),
        ], 
        return_exceptions=True
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

P.S. Didn't test this code much!

Comment: Thanks, you gave me quite a few ideas!